# Check image size before storing it in delphi

Tags: delphi

how do I check image size before storing it to the database. I need to check image size before a user can upload an image to avoid errors of not being able to write to the database.

Below is a snipet of how I am inserting images currently in my database, it works fine except for images that are larger than the field size I am storing it in the database.

The image field in the database is of `LONGVARBINARY` 484 Physical Length

```
              dtm.cds.Insert;
              Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile(OpenPictureDialog1.FileName);
              Image1.Visible := false;
              Field := TBlobField(dtm.cds.FieldByName('PICTURE'));
              Stream := dtm.cds.CreateBlobStream(field, bmwrite);

              JpegImage := TJPEGImage.Create;
              try
                     JpegImage.Assign(Image1.Picture);
                     JpegImage.SaveToStream(Stream);
              finally
                     Stream.Free;
                     dtm.cds.Post;
                     dtm.cds.ApplyUpdates(-1);
              end;
```

Comment: 484 bytes (!) long images will be either very small, horrible to see or impossible to store. Think about nothing else than changing your schema to allow storing unlimited amount of data.

Comment: @Victoria Not sure if that's 484 bytes. I cam currently storing an image with size of 11.7 KB. If that was in bytes then it would be 0.484 KB and that image would not fit in the field.

Comment: If it's not 484 then show us the actual schema for the table.  What DB are you using?  What database components?  How are you connecting?  Direct?  ODBC? Something else?  What version of Delphi?

Comment: Try to perform the transaction. If it fails, roll back and report an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TField` has a [`Size`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TField.Size) property:

> Indicates the size used in the definition of the physical database field for data types that support different sizes.

Try something more like this:

```
MemStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
try
  JpegImage := TJPEGImage.Create;
  try
    Picture := TPicture.Create;
    try
      Picture.LoadFromFile(OpenPictureDialog1.FileName);
      JpegImage.Assign(Picture.Graphic);
    finally
      Picture.Free;
    end;
    JpegImage.SaveToStream(MemStream);
  finally
    JpegImage.Free;
  end;
  Field := dtm.cds.FieldByName('PICTURE');
  if MemStream.Size > Field.Size then
    raise Exception.Create('Image as a JPEG is too large to store!');
  dtm.cds.Insert;
  try
    Stream := dtm.cds.CreateBlobStream(Field, bmWrite);
    try
      Stream.CopyFrom(MemStream, 0);
    finally
      Stream.Free;
    end;
    dtm.cds.Post;
  except
    dtm.cds.Cancel;
    raise;
  end;
finally
  MemStream.Free;
end;
dtm.cds.ApplyUpdates(-1);
```

Comment: A LONGVARBINARY is a variable length data type, the database will not impose any length constraint. That's why it's mapped to a blob, whose size is whatever you set.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz if that were true (and I'm not debating it isn't) then I don't see any reason why the OP would be having trouble posting images of varying sizes, unless there really is some max limit being hit. I guess it depends on what kind of DB is being used. The OP hasn't stated that yet.

Comment: Indeed, OP has been very discrete about the database level, in previous questions also. I had thought about a trigger but who knows..

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`Size`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TStream.Size) property of the stream you're using. Of course you need to know the exact size that the database allows. E.g.:

```
const
   MAXIMAGESIZE = ???;
   IMAGEOVERSIZE = 'Image size is larger than allowed';
..
  ...
  try
      JpegImage.Assign(Image1.Picture);
      JpegImage.SaveToStream(Stream);
      if Stream.Size <= MAXIMAGESIZE then begin
          dtm.cds.Post;
          dtm.cds.ApplyUpdates(-1);
      end else begin
          dtm.cds.Cancel;
          raise Exception.Create(IMAGEOVERSIZE);
      end;
  finally
      Stream.Free;
  end;
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try that and report back shortly.

Comment: "*Of course you need to know the exact size that the database allows*" - the [`TField.Size`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TField.Size) property tells you that.

Comment: Thank you. I know the maximum size of the field now. I wasn't sure how the table was defined. I will use this method to restrict images of within the size limit.

Comment: I would suggest saving the JPEG to a temp `TMemoryStream` first, and then upload it only if it will fit, don't even `Insert` a new record otherwise. If you save the JPEG directly to the blob field and it exceeds the blob's size, you can get an error the code above is not accounting for. Also, you shouldn't be using an invisible `TImage`, use your own `TPicture` object instead

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes good point thank you. Actually that's the reason that made me check for the image size.

Comment: @LionsFan: then why not just catch the original error if it is raised?

Comment: @Remy a blob won't raise an exception for the amount of data you attempt to store. Where it can do so is indicated by the use of "maximum" in the doc you linked. The meaningful differences in your answer are: you're using "field.size" instead of a constant and you're avoiding an "insert" at the expense of an additional stream.

Comment: BTW a blob's size is what you set. It's not set/used by the VCL otherwise.